# vCenter 5.1 Appliance SSO - password

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-server

After installing vCenter 5.1 appliance on a virtual machine (run by ESXi),  it automatically set embedded SSO credentials. While the administrator user-name is always admin@System-Domain and the password is unknown.

How can I know the SSO administrator password?

VMware KB claims the SSO admin password is the user admin password of the machine - "vmware", although it does not work when I try to install vSphere web client; it fails to connect vCenter using SSO.

Did you encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I read that vCenter server appliance create a temporary SSO admin password during installation and deletes it right after installation is finished.

So, I will have to create an external SSO